# Полностью не переведена страница Code of Conduct

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Если перейти по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct), то можно заметить, что страница полностью на английском языке.

[image: нелокализованная страница Code of Conduct]

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Предлагаю выкладывать перевод в виде отдельного "вопроса" и дать возможность участникам высказаться и проголосовать за отдельные корректировки в рамках общей канвы, чтобы сгладить те самые острые углы про иронию, бинайс и т.п.

Comment: А откуда вообще взялась ссылка? На MSE, я например, видел строку уведомления в заголовке. На ruSO такой не было.

Comment: @alexolut Вот это кстати правда, уведомлений у нас об этом нет. На ссылку перешёл черёз URL (добавив `ru.`, когда увидел эту страницу на enSO), хотел глянуть есть ли у нас такая штука, которая многих так пугает, в том числе и на нашей мете.

Comment: Ссылка, как оказалось, есть со страницы [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @alexolut, причём их там сразу 2. [be-nice] туда же редиректит..

Comment: @vp_arth ещё одно доказательство того, что бинайс навязывается :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевод был добавлен и сегодня отобразится на сайте. Code of Conduct теперь называется *нормами поведения*.

Ознакомиться с новыми правилами можно здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct.